# Overflow checking of which of these is possible and how? byte, Int16, Int32 and float

Tags: c#, .net, overflow

I have to multiply a variable with a multiplying factor. The data types of my variable will be either of a byte, an Int16, an Int32 or a float.

I tried `checked` keyword usage as per the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx), but it did not compile. For reference, see below code snippet:

`byte mv = default(byte);
mv = checked(Convert.ToByte(data.Value.ToString()) * Convert.ToByte(MultiplyingFactor));`

My confusion being: does `checked` keyword overflow checking at runtime apply only to `integer` type variables?

How to check *overflow* of multiplying operation at runtime for `byte`, `Int16`, `Int32` and `float`? My requirement is to replace the destination variable with either min or max value of data type when overflow happens.

Comment: What's the compilation error message?

Comment: Handle the `OverflowException` that happens in `checked` execution  context.

Answer (score 2):

Which error are you getting? In this example

```
byte b1 = 10;
byte b2 = 10;
byte b3 = checked(b1 * b2);
```

the compile error you get says `error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'.`

The same happens with

```
byte b3 = b1 * b2;
```

This does not mean that it's doing some compile-time overflow checking, just that the result of the multiplication of two bytes is an int, not a byte.

In the case of the byte you are showing here, you could get what you want with something like this, instead:

```
int res = b1 * b2;
byte bRes = 0;
if (res > byte.MaxValue) {
    bRes = byte.MaxValue;
} else if (res < byte.MinValue) {
    bRes = byte.MinValue;
} else {
    bRes = (byte)res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the result of the calculation back to `byte` because it will be done as an integer:

```
mv = checked((byte)(Convert.ToByte(data.Value.ToString()) * Convert.ToByte(MultiplyingFactor)));
```

Although you could catch a `System.OverflowException` that resulted from this code, and set your byte value appropriately, I don't think that's the right approach for this particular example.

Instead I think you should write a method to convert the int to a byte as follows:

```
public static byte ClipToByte(int value)
{
    if (value < byte.MinValue)
        return byte.MinValue;
    else if (value > byte.MaxValue)
        return byte.MaxValue;
    else
        return (byte) value;
}
```

Which you could use like this:

```
mv = ClipToByte(Convert.ToByte(data.Value.ToString()) * Convert.ToByte(MultiplyingFactor));
```

And write similar methods for other types.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out, the following unit tests are passing, except for the last unit test for float overflow checking:

```
    [TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(OverflowException))]
    public void Test108_Byte_Overflow_Test()
    {
        byte max = byte.MaxValue;
        byte mf = (byte)3;
        byte b = checked((byte)(max * mf));
    }

    [TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(OverflowException))]
    public void Test108_Int16_Overflow_Test()
    {
        Int16 max = Int16.MaxValue;
        Int16 mf = (Int16)3;
        Int16 i = checked((Int16)(max * mf));
    }

    [TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(OverflowException))]
    public void Test109_Int32_Overflow_Test()
    {
        int max = int.MaxValue;
        int mf = 3;
        int i = checked(max * mf);
    }

    [TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(OverflowException))]
    public void Test110_Float_Overflow_Test()
    {
        float max = float.MaxValue;
        float mf = 3f;
        float f = checked(max * mf);
    }
```